inserting symbol in my lyx file
I would insert the symbol of a square in my text. Inserting from menu: insert-> special character ->   square (25A2) works in my lyx file, but rendering as pdf does not work. I get:
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
I tried to add the command:
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{25A2}{$\square$}

in preamble, but it does not work. I get 'undefined control sequence'. Obviously the name \square is not correct.
Any hints?
thank you
p.

Welcome to TeX.SE.

The \square macro is defined in the amsfonts package. Hence, you also need to run \usepackage{amsfonts} -- or, with slightly more generality, \usepackage{amssymb} -- in the preamble.

If LyX inserts the symbol, it should take care of loading the required packages. Can you go to Document > Settings > Math Options and make sure everything is set to "Load automatically" ?

If that doesn't work, please post a minimal .lyx example, and @ me and I can take a look.

@scottkosky
I have created a test lyx file with no commands in the preamble, but everything set to "Load automatically". Yer it does not work.
How can i attach my file?

Adding
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{25A2}{$\square$}
to the preamble does the trick
thank you

@xpol Where do you find this symbol in Insert > Symbols? can you put a screenshot showing the dialog with the symbol you chose highlighted? I can't find it in my "Geometry" section in Insert > Symbols.

I don't know how to include a picture, here.
inset > special character > symbols > geometric shapes
then i chose the third symbol from the left, first line.
I am using LyX Version 2.4.0~RC4

Step 1
Document →
Settings... →
Fonts
→ ☑ Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX\LuaTeX) →
→ Roman: DejaVu Serif (or some other with the glyph)  →
Close
Setp 2
Insert →
Special Character →
Symbols...
→ Category: Geometric Shapes
→ Select the 3th symbol (U+25A2) →
OK
Or alternatively in Linux: Ctrl + Shift + u, then type 25a2 (This is not a LyX specific method. For other OS must be a similar method to enter unicode characters in any program).
In any case, this should produce this compilable code showing a ▢, starting with a new file:
%% LyX 2.3.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}
▢
\end{document}

If you mark this symbol as math code, Lyx will load automatically insert amstext and a macro definition to use \lyxmathsym{▢} while inserting the symbol already in math mode will use \text{▢} but in the PDF the symbol look exactly the same.

Yes that way works. Which other fonts with that glyph, besides dejaVu?
The alternative,  Ctrl + Shift + 25a2, does not work.
I am using lyx Version 2.4.0~RC4 on linux
thank you

@xpol (1) Depend on each font, probably Symbola, but most fonts do not have this rare symbols  (2) Sorry, my fault, the shorcut is really Ctrl + Shift + u  (then you should see  a underlined "u") then you can free all the three  keys and  jtype the code.
